# why mathematica Holds the Solve on the set of equations in the diagonal a matrix?

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, hold

Say I have a simple function

```
F[x_, y_, z_, r_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := (1 - a + b - (b/3) (c x + d (y + z + r))) x
```

And I want to solve the set of equations given by:

```
x == F[x,y,z,r,a,b,c,d]
y == F[y,x,z,r,a,b,c,d]
z == F[z,x,y,r,a,b,c,d]
r == F[r,x,y,z,a,b,c,d]
```

The variables are `x,y,z,r`; `a,b,c,d` are parameters;
and the only important position is the first of the 4 variables in each equation of the type `x==F[x,y,z,r,...]`

I figured I should solve this system by the command

```
Solve[Diagonal[Table[m==n,{m,{x,y,z,r}},{n,{F[x,y,z,r,a,b,c,d],F[y,x,z,r,a,b,c,d],F[z,y,x,r,a,b,c,d],F[r,y,z,x,a,b,c,d]}}]],{x,y,z,r}]
```

However, Mathematica doesn't evaluate the Solve command, it simply prints back the command without giving it a try...

- What am I missing?
- Is there a simpler way to build the system of equations?
- Is it possible to do for any number of variables? (here, I have 4 variables, ideally I'd want it working for n variables)

In math, the general system of equations would look like this:

```
$$
\vec{x}=\vec{F}(\vec{x})
$$
```

and I want to solve for each component of $\vec{x}$

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you had defined `F` before trying `Solve`? Is the `F`  in your notebook blue (undefined) or black (properly defined)? Does `Solve` return an error of any kind?

This is what I get:

```
ClearAll[F]
F[x_, y_, z_, r_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := (1 - a + b - (b/3) (c x + d (y + z + r))) x

Solve[
  {x == F[x, y, z, r, a, b, c, d], 
   y == F[y, x, z, r, a, b, c, d],
   z == F[z, y, x, r, a, b, c, d], 
   r == F[r, y, z, x, a, b, c, d]},
  {x, y, z, r}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect F was defined as F[x,y,z,a,b,c,d] without the `r`

Comment: @Girardi Yep that could be a reason as well. I tend to add a `Clear` before any function definition to make sure that old definitions don't linger etc.